# highlight overexposed areas in a UIImage

Tags: ios, macos, graphics

I'm making a simple camera app for iOS and MAC. After the user snaps a picture it generates a UIimage on iOS (NSImage on MAC). I want to be able to highlight the areas in the image that is over exposed. Basically the overexposed areas would blink when that image is displayed.

Anybody knows the algorithm on how to tell where on the image is overexposed. Do I just add up the R,G,B values at each pixel. And if the total at each pixel is greater than a certain amount, then start blinking that pixel, and do that for all pixels?

Or do I have to do some complicated math from outer space to figure it out?

Thanks
rough

Comment: With RGB, if any of the values are at the maximum, then clipping may have occurred. "Overexposed" is subjective. Define "overexposed", and start there.

Comment: overexposed, or "blown out" parts of the image as photographers called it. I guess that means any parts with the maximum value? I really dont know for sure, but my camera can blink parts of the image that are blown out of overexposed. This is what I mean, but I want to do it in the app.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to traverse the image, depending on your desired accuracy and precision, you can combine skipping and averaging pixels to come up with a smooth region...
it will depend on the details of you color space, but imagine YUV space (because you only need to look at one value, the Y or luminance):

if 240/255 is considered white, then a greater value of say 250/255 would be over exposed and you could mark it, then display in an overlay.